# ngOnInit can't update a local variable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Pretty simple really, I have a variable set up on the page which I use to create a bunch of boxes on the font end. I initialise this variable like so:

```
organisations: Organisation[];
```

and then in `ngOnInit` I am getting some data back from storage which I will then use to populate this variable. So the whole page looks like this:

```
export class SelectOrganisationPage implements OnInit {
  organisations: Organisation[];

  constructor(private authentication: AuthenticationService, private storage: Storage) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.storage.get(USER_DETAILS).then(user => {
      const parsedUser: User = JSON.parse(user);

      parsedUser.organisations.forEach(org => {
        if (!org.active) {
          return;
        }

        this.organisations.push(org);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

On the line `this.organisations.push(org);` I get the following error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

I don't understand why it can't read `this.organisations` at that point. Unless I am mistaken on the actual error?

This is contextually different to the other question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error says `organisations` is undefined, so you have to initialize it with an empty array.

Try like this:

```
organisations: Organisation[] = [];
```

Comment: Fantastic yep, completely forgot about that well spotted!